# Magento 2 set & get Registry values

Tags: magento2, event-observer, register, registry, magento-2.1.8

I want to set an array in registry in `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` event observer and read this in a phtml page.

The following code will give blank result
.

**=> Code :**

```
namespace NameSpace\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class RestrictAddToCart implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;  

    protected $_product;  

    protected $_responseFactory;

    protected $_url;
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    )
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {          
        $this->_registry->register('slct_options', $observer->getRequest()->getParams());
        $customRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('my-page');            
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();     
        die(); 
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**=> phtml :**

```
<?php 
print_r( $block->getRegisterData());     
 ?>
```

**=> Block :**

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Customblock extends Template
{    
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }           
     public function getRegisterData()
    {         
        return $this->_registry->registry('slct_options');    
    }
}
```

Comment: When you execute your code, what is the output ?

Comment: The code will give blank output

Comment: try to do print_r($objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('slct_options'), true);     @JancyAbraham

Comment: @JancyAbraham, please make sure, in your observer's execute function, $observer->getRequest()->getParams() is null or not . Try to print it.

Comment: @MGento , $observer->getRequest()->getParams() contains an array

Comment: @ Keyur, it is not working

Comment: @Jancy,  are you sure your event observer is being invoked? at the beginning of your execute function, just put  die('obser is hit');  and cache onnu clear cheythekku

Comment: Ya my observer is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The registry is getting cleared after the server sends a response. Each new request starts with an empty registry.

If you want to transfer data from one request to another you should use the session instead.

Comment: not working :-(

Comment: did you get it ?

Comment: No,still it is not working. When I remove the die(); then it is not redirected to my page

Comment: Registry will not work as per the scenario here. You have to use session instead. This could save your time.

Comment: ya, now I am checking with session

Answer (score 3):

The registry will load once the controller is loaded. One more point, registry function should be called in block file only. It is the best way of doing.

So as you are calling the registry inside the controller, it wont work in that way. You need to specify block file and then you access that value to template from block. Even template definition and values should be passed through block only.

Edit:

```
/**
  * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
  */

 protected $_registry;

 /**
 * ...
 * ...
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
 */
public function __construct(
    ...,
    ...,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    ...
) {
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    ...
    ...
}

 /**
 * Setting custom variable in registry
 *
 */

public function setCustomVariable()
{
     $this->_registry->register('custom_var', 'Added Value');
}

/**
 * Retrieving custom variable from registry
 * @return string
 */
public function getCustomVariable()
{
     return $this->_registry->registry('custom_var');
}
```

Here you can see that I set the registry with `setCustomVariable()` this function and I am trying to pull the registry with this `getCustomVariable()`.. 
Now we need to call this `getCustomVariable()` in phtml file. Now it will work.

Comment: I have updated the code, still it is not working.

Comment: You are trying to get the registry without setting it!!

Comment: I have set the registry in the observer .

Comment: I cant see any setRegistry in observer. see my updated answer!!

Comment: This is my code
 $this->_registry->register('slct_options', $observer->getRequest()->getParams());
Please check the RestrictAddToCart class

Comment: http://i.prntscr.com/vvFmyRLrS226uVmwAwEFDA.png

Comment: are you sure you are receiving values from  $observer->getRequest()->getParams() ?? Because you will get the values from this $observer->getEvent() !!! can you print the values  of $observer->getRequest()->getParams() by using print_r($observer->getRequest()->getParams());

Comment: I have tried this too  $this->_registry->register('slct_options', '123');

Answer (score 2):

You can get the registry value as below

```
<?php   

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$slct_options = $objectManager->create("Magento\Framework\Registry")->registry('slct_options');
```

**Note**: It's a good practice not to use ObjectManager directly in phtml file. Do it by using dependency injection.

Comment: I have updated the code, still it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, using objectManager in your code is bad. There are places you are permitted to do that, do your research.

I personally think, you need to create a block and define a function that gets the registry value from your block, that will be accessible in your template by calling the block's function

Comment: I have updated the code, still it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$slct_options = $objectManager->get("Magento\Framework\Registry")- >registry('slct_options');
```

use **get** instead of **create**.

It create new object you will get null values

as previously said it is last option to use object manager try to add in constructor.

[for reference](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManagerInterface.php)